# Add a `tsrange` column in database migration

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a column `tsrange` in a migration for a PostgreSQL Database. Is there a way to do this in a Laravel Migration? How can I specify this kind of column?

Comment: did you try addColumn? on Blueprint object? (`$table->addColumn('tsrange', 'my_tsrange_col')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this library: https://github.com/bosnadev/database.

Or try to implement it yourself:

```
public function tsrange($column)
{
    return $this->addColumn('tsrange', $column);
}
```